# Is it possible to override stored procedures in a SQL project referencing another project?

Tags: sql-server, dacpac

I have a legacy database solution that has a core database and custom databases. This gets deployed using SQL compare in quite a manual way, I'd like to change that to use DacPac's to deploy.

The core database project contains all the common tables, stored procedures etc.
The custom database is for a specific customer that references the core database project.

What I'm trying to do is override/replace a stored procedure in the core database project to include these customisations (SP name and parameters are the same but the stored procedure body is different) but when I try that visual studio shows a `SQL71508: The model already has an element that has the same name` error. Is it possible to override?

What I'm trying to avoid is coding the base SP to check for the existence of an "override" sp and call that instead as there are quite a few overrides and many customers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your customer has access to the back end and for some reason you really don't want that customer to see the core code, then you can create a [post deployment script](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3006/working-with-pre-and-post-deployment-scripts) with a [scripting variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables?view=sql-server-ver15):

Scripts.PostDeployment.sql:

```
:setvar customerName "customCustomer"

if $(customerName) = 'customCustomer'
    exec ('alter procedure dbo.someProc as ...');
```

But I don't imagine this is usually necessary.  I wouldn't hide the the complexity:

```
create procedure dbo.someProc
as

declare @customer nvarchar(255) = (select customerName from dbo.currentCustomer);

if @customer = 'customCustomer'
begin
    ...
end

else 
begin
    ...
end
```